# How to test for logic operator precedence

Tags: computer-puzzle, computer-science

While coding in Python, I realized I couldn't remember which is evaluated first:

`and` (the logical conjunctive operator),
`or` (the logical disjunctive operator).

Of course, I could've used parentheses (or looked it up), but I wanted to try to find out for myself. I tried endless combinations of `False`, `True`, `and`, and `or` but could not figure it out.

**Given a language with unknown operator precedence, where operators of equal precedence evaluate left-to-right, find a way to conclusively determine whether the logical conjunction or the logical disjunction is evaluated first.**

You can only use `False`, `True`, `and`, and `or` in your answer.

Note: You may assume that `or` and `and` definitely have different precedence.

Comment: Are we assuming operator precedence either (1) evaluates all `and` left to right and then all `or` left to right, or (2) evaluates all `or` left to right and then all `and` left to right?

Comment: @noedne Yes. Otherwise they'd have the same precedence

Comment: @noedne That is correct.

Comment: Then should this assumption be added to the question?

Comment: @noedne edited.

Comment: Nice edit. Do we also assume that `and` and `or` have different precedence?

Comment: Yes, as stated (slightly unclearly) in the question. Let me clarify that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> `True or True and False`
>
>  Giving `True` means 'and' then 'or'. Giving `False` means 'or' then 'and'.

Bonus:

> `False and True or True`
>
>  Also use this to test if the precedence is same. If both tests are resulting different value (first test gives `False` and second test gives `True`) then the precedence is same.

Comment: Wow, how did I not think of that… *facepalm*
Good job!

Comment: The middle value is actually irrelevant. It could be either true or false and the test would still work the same.